# Problema con la adaptación de un código usando clases

Tags: python, class

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo del Python con el libro "Python Programming Fundamentals" de Kent D.Lee y llevo bastantes horas intentando resolver un ejercicio, que basicamente trata de coger un código y modificarlo para que realice el mismo trabajo pero en vez de utilizar listas paralelas utilice una clase que nosotros definamos.

El código base basicamente es un programa que cuando se ejecuta sale una ventana emergente de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para insertar un recordatorio con un título (para ese recordatorio).

El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:

> Vuelva al programa original de Reminder! y rehágalo de forma que el
> programa Reminder! contenga una clase llamada Reminder que sustituya
> las listas paralelas de recordatorios y notas por una lista de
> recordatorios. Esta lista debería ser una lista de objetos Reminder.
> Un objeto Reminder mantiene un registro de su ubicación x,y en la
> pantalla. También tiene algún texto que se proporciona cuando se crea.
> Un Reminder debe encargarse de crear los objetos Text y Toplevel para
> poder mostrar una nota. Finalmente, los métodos definidos en un
> Recordatorio incluyen undraw (para retirar la ventana), getX para
> devolver el valor X de la ubicación de la ventana, getY igualmente
> obtiene el valor Y de la ubicación de la ventana. El método getText
> debe devolver el campo de texto. Por último, el manejador setDelete
> debería establecer el manejador que se llamará cuando se elimine un
> recordatorio. Escribe esta clase y modifica la aplicación Reminder!
> para que utilice esta nueva clase. Este es un esquema de la definición
> de la clase Reminder. Tienes que terminar de definirla y modificar el
> programa para utilizarla.

```
> class Reminder:
>     def __init__(self,x,y,text):
>         ...
>     def undraw(self):
>         ...
>     def getX(self):
>         ...
>     def getY(self):
>         ...
>         
>     def getText(self):
>         ...
>         
>     def setDeleteHandler(self,command):
>         
>         ...
```

El código "Reminder" que viene completo en el libro es el siguiente:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

def addReminder(text,x,y,notes,reminders):
    notewin = tkinter.Toplevel()
    notewin.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    notewin.geometry("+"+str(x)+"+"+str(y))
    
    reminder = tkinter.Text(notewin,bg="yellow", width=30,height=15)

    reminder.insert(tkinter.END,text)
    
    reminder.pack()

    
    notes.append(notewin)
    reminders.append(reminder)
    
    
    def deleteWindowHandler():
        print("Window Deleted")
        notewin.withdraw()
        notes.remove(notewin)
        reminders.remove(reminder)
    
    notewin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", deleteWindowHandler)
    
    
def main():
    
    def post():
        print("Post")
        addReminder(note.get("1.0",tkinter.END), root.winfo_rootx()+5,root.winfo_rooty()+5,notes,reminders)
        note.delete("1.0",tkinter.END)               
   
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    
    root.title("Reminder!")
    root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

    notes = []
    reminders = []

    bar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    
    fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(bar,tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.quit)
    bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fileMenu)
    root.config(menu=bar)
    
    mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(root,borderwidth=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    mainFrame.pack()
    
    note = tkinter.Text(mainFrame,bg="yellow", width=30,height=15)
    note.pack()
    
    tkinter.Button(mainFrame,text="New Reminder!", command=post).pack()
    
    #Code for the Entry and Text widgets in this application
    titleFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainFrame)
    titleFrame.pack()
    
    noteTitle = tkinter.StringVar()
    titleLabel = tkinter . Label ( titleFrame , text =" Title :")
    titleLabel . grid ( row =1 , column =1 , sticky = tkinter . E)
    titleText = tkinter . Entry ( titleFrame , textvariable = noteTitle )
    titleText . grid ( row =1 , column =2 , columnspan =2 , sticky = tkinter . E+ tkinter . W)
        
  
    try:
        print("reading reminders.txt file")
        file = open("reminders.txt","r")
        x = int(file.readline())
        y = int(file.readline())
        root.geometry("+"+str(x)+"+"+str(y))
        
        
        line = file.readline()
        while line.strip() != "":
            x = int(line)
            y = int(file.readline())
            text = ""
            line = file.readline()
            while line.strip() != "____....____._._._":
                text = text + line
                line = file.readline()
                
            text = text.strip()
            
            addReminder(text,x,y,notes,reminders)
            
            line = file.readline()
    except:
        print("reminders.txt not found")
        
        
    
    def appClosing():
        print("Application Closing")
        file = open("reminders.txt","w")
        
        file.write(str(root.winfo_x())+"\n")
        file.write(str(root.winfo_y())+"\n")
        
        for i in range(len(notes)):
            print(notes[i].winfo_rootx())
            print(notes[i].winfo_rooty())
            print(reminders[i].get("1.0",tkinter.END))
            
            file.write(str(notes[i].winfo_rootx())+"\n")
            file.write(str(notes[i].winfo_rooty())+"\n")
            file.write(reminders[i].get("1.0",tkinter.END)+"\n")
            file.write("____....____._._._\n")
            
        file.close()
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
        sys.exit()
        
    
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", appClosing)  
    
         
    tkinter.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

He estado intentando comprender como resolver el ejercicio pero no soy capaz de comprender como puedo sustituir las listas notes[] y reminders[] por una sola lista que contenga elementos del tipo Reminder. ¿Como puedo definir esa clase de tipo "Reminder"?
Y una vez definida ¿como implimento esa nueva clase en el código?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas con usar listas paralelas:

- No hay nada que indique que dos o más listas son paralelas. Esto solo se puede deducir al examinar el código y notar que las dos listas siempre aparecen juntas y sujetas a las mismas operaciones.
- Es fácil que las listas pierdan sincronización si actualizas una, pero no la otra. Una vez desincronizadas, toda la información se corrompe.
- Es trabajoso y molesto tener que escribir la misma operación (inserción, por ejemplo) en cada una de las listas para mantener su consistencia.
- Hace crecer el código y disminuye su legibilidad.

#### Caso de estudio

Nota: tu código es demasiado extenso y complejo, por lo que inventare un problemilla de más fácil comprensión.

En este caso tenemos un taller automotriz que recibe vehículos (identificados por su matrícula), los que son asignados a mecánicos (identificados por número de empleado).

Una solución con listas paralelas:

```
vehiculos = []
mecanicos = []
```

Cuando se recibe un vehículo hay que agregar un nuevo elemento:

```
vehiculos.append("GHYT23")
mecanicos.append(455)
```

y cuando se termina, hay que sacar un elemento de cada lista, etc.

#### Solución con clases

Creamos una clase que represente un trabajo de mecánica. Para esto requiero un vehículo y un mecánico, los que son asignados al momento de crear el trabajo:

```
class Trabajo:
    def __init__(self, vehiculo, mecanico):
        self.vehiculo = vehiculo
        self.mecanico = mecanico

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vehículo {self.vehiculo} atendido por {self.mecanico}"
```

Un objeto de esta clase describe un sólo trabajo de taller. En un taller hay muchos trabajos, por lo que necesitamos un *contenedor* que nos dirá los trabajos en desarrollo:

```
# Taller es un contenedor: una lista de todos los taller en el taller
taller = []
```

Tenemos una sola lista. Si recibimos nuevos vehículos, creamos un objeto `Trabajo` por cada uno y lo agregamos al contenedor

```
#  Se reciben dos vehiculos que entran a taller
nuevo_trabajo = Trabajo("HHTTY45", 501)
taller.append(nuevo_trabajo)
nuevo_trabajo = Trabajo("XYZ8834", 502)
taller.append(nuevo_trabajo)
```

Veamos que trabajos hay en el taller

```
#   Veamos como está el taller
print("Taller:")
for trabajo in taller:
    print(trabajo)
```

produce:

```
Taller:
Vehículo HHTTY45 atendido por 501
Vehículo XYZ8834 atendido por 502
```

y luego se termina de reparar un vehiculo (digamos que es el último que entró, para simplificar). Hay que sacarlo del taller:

```
#   Se terminó el último trabajo
taller.pop()
```

Nuevamente, veamos como quedo el taller:

```
#   Veamos como queda
print("Taller:")
for trabajo in taller:
    print(trabajo)
```

produce:

```
Taller:
Vehículo HHTTY45 atendido por 501
```

Finalmente, si tienes un objeto `Trabajo`, puedes acceder a sus componentes directamente:

```
work1 = Trabajo("XXYYXX9", 423)
print("El vehiculo es ", work1.vehiculo)
print("El mecánico es ", work1.mecanico)
```

#### Resumen

Debes crear una clase que reciba la nota y el recordatorio y los almacene.

Debes crear un contenedor para almacenar los objetos creados; no pueden andar volando por ahí, especialmente si su número es indeterminado.